# SQL Server : JOIN with multi-level or tree nodes

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2012

I have these two tables in SQL Server 2012:

1. In this table I have categories and subcategories

   ```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Categories](
       [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
       [ParentCategoryId] [int] NULL,
       [CategoryName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
       [Slug] [nvarchar](150) NULL
   ) ON [PRIMARY]
   ```
2. This table have photo items

   ```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Photos](
       [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
       [CategoryId] [int] NULL,
       [FileName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
       [Slug] [nvarchar](150) NULL
   ) ON [PRIMARY]
   ```

I want to create a SQL `SELECT` on the `Photos` table which returns the `Slug` which is the URL of the photo item (not the actual image) and the category slug.

I need this information from DB:

/category-slug/subcategory-slug/photo-slug

I have this `SELECT` which returns the slug only for one level/node of the category

```
SELECT * 
FROM   [PHOTOS] 
       JOIN [CATEGORIES] 
         ON PHOTOS.CATEGORY = CATEGORIES.ID
```

This returns only the current category or subcategory slug, but I need the parent slug too in order to construct the full url

How can I get all the Parent nodes from `Categories` in one select ?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? SQL Server, MYSQL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following recursive query to build the path hierarchy for the photos
It assumes that the slug contains the path of the category, e.g. category-slug, hence in the expression I am concatenating with '/'

```
WITH categoryPath(Id,Slug)
AS
(
    SELECT Id,Slug FROM Categories
    WHERE ParentCategoryId IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Categories.Id
          ,CAST(categoryPath.Slug + '/' + categories.Slug AS NVARCHAR(150))  
    FROM Categories
         JOIN categoryPath ON Categories.ParentCategoryId=categoryPath.Id
)
SELECT * FROM Photos 
              JOIN categoryPath ON Photos.CategoryId = categoryPath.Id;
```

Comment: I have run this query, but it returns no results

Comment: no, It's ok, I had the parent categories set to 0 instead of NULL, now after I have changed to NULL it works :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to join to bring in the category table twice. I've done that as a left join below in case some photos are in a top level category. If not you can remove the "LEFT".

```
select p.*,c1.*,c2.*
from
    Photos p
    JOIN Categories c1 on
        p.CategoryId = c1.Id
    LEFT JOIN Categories c2 on
        c1.ParentCategoryId = c2.Id
```

Or if you might have any number of "generations" of parents, you'll need to do some recursion ... I see someone has beaten me to that!

Comment: Probably I will not have more than 1 or 2 subcategories. If it's not possible then I will try to live with only 1 subcategory.